# Не срабатывает миграция в EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, миграция

Я добавил новых класс и поле к уже существующему, а теперь хочу запустить миграцию. Ввожу "add-migration addUsers" но генерируется пустой файл. В чем может быть проблема?

```
public partial class addUsers : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
    }
}
```

**Существующий класс**

```
public class Task
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Title is required.")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Author { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public UserProfile Owner { get; set; }  //<- Добавил это поле
}
```

**Новый класс**

```
public class UserProfile
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
}
```

**DBSets**

```
public class TasksDatabase : DbContext
{

    public TasksDatabase() : base("eTask")
        { }

    public DbSet<Task> Tasks { get; set; }

    public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
}
```

**последняя миграция**

```
public override void Up()
{
    CreateTable(
        "dbo.Tasks",
        c => new
            {
                Id = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                Title = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 256),
                Author  = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 256),
                Description  = c.String(nullable: true)
            })
        .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
        .Index(t => t.Name, unique: true, name: "NameIndex");          
}

public override void Down()
{
    DropIndex("dbo.Tasks", "NameIndex");
}
```

Comment: А каких изменений в БД вы ожидаете?

Comment: @PavelMayorov Добавления нового поля в таблицу Tasks. И добавления новой таблицы UserProfile.

Comment: А вы DbSet добавить не забыли?

Comment: Кстати, в БД новые поле и таблица уже есть?

Comment: @PavelMayorov DBSet добавил. Нет. Она же не появится пока я не сделаю update-database

Comment: @Maksims, `InitialCreate` у вас создан?

Comment: @Андрей да. Я делал миграцию 2 дня назад, где создавал таблицу Tasks  и все сработало.

Comment: @Maksims, содержимое приведите

Comment: @Андрей добавил к описанию вопроса

Comment: @Maksims, ок, а что еще в папке `Migrations` есть?

Comment: Возможно необходимо указать проект попробуйте: Add-Migration addUsers -ProjectName "MyProject"

Comment: @Андрей По мимо миграций там есть автоматически сгенерированный файл  internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<eTask.Domain.ApplicationDbContext>
    {
        public Configuration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        }

Comment: @RusGIS попробовал, не сработало

Comment: Вопрос все еще актуален .

Comment: @AK Вы можете помочь в этом вопросе?